# Show product thumbnails in product tab in category admin does not work

Tags: php, adminhtml, grid, plugin

I am using following code to show product thumbnails in category products tab in admin panel. Magento Version 1.9.1.1

app/etc/modules/My_Thumbnail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Thumbnail>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </My_Thumbnail>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/My/Thumbnail/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Thumbnail>
            <version>1.0.0.2</version>
        </My_Thumbnail>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_category_tab_product>My_Thumbnail_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product</catalog_category_tab_product>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then Copied app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Product.php to
app/code/local/My/Thumbnail/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Category/Tab/Product.php
and edited as follows:

```
<?php
class My_Thumbnail_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('catalog_category_products');
    $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}

public function getCategory()
{
    return Mage::registry('category');
}

protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
{
    // Set custom filter for in category flag
    if ($column->getId() == 'in_category') {
        $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
        if (empty($productIds)) {
            $productIds = 0;
        }
        if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$productIds));
        }
        elseif(!empty($productIds)) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin'=>$productIds));
        }
    }
    else {
        parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }
    return $this;
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    if ($this->getCategory()->getId()) {
        $this->setDefaultFilter(array('in_category'=>1));
    }
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                      ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                      ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                      ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                      ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                      ->addStoreFilter($this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                      ->joinField('position',
                                  'catalog/category_product',
                                  'position',
                                  'product_id=entity_id',
                                  'category_id='.(int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0),
                                  'left');
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    if ($this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
        $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
        if (empty($productIds)) {
            $productIds = 0;
        }
        $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$productIds));
    }

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    if (!$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
        $this->addColumn('in_category', array(
            'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
            'name'      => 'in_category',
            'values'    => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
            'align'     => 'center',
            'index'     => 'entity_id'
        ));
    }
    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
        'sortable'  => true,
        'width'     => '60',
        'index'     => 'entity_id'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),
        'index'     => 'name'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('image', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Image'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'image',
        'width'     => '97',
        'renderer' => 'My_Thumbnail_Block_Adminhtml_Template_Grid_Renderer_Image'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
        'width'     => '80',
        'index'     => 'sku'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('price', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price'),
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'width'     => '1',
        'currency_code' => (string) Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE),
        'index'     => 'price'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('position', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Position'),
        'width'     => '1',
        'type'      => 'number',
        'index'     => 'position',
        'editable'  => !$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()
        //'renderer'  => 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_renderer_input'
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
}

protected function _getSelectedProducts()
{
    $products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected_products');
    if (is_null($products)) {
        $products = $this->getCategory()->getProductsPosition();
        return array_keys($products);
    }
    return $products;
}

}
```

Then Created a renderer at app/code/local/My/Thumbnail/Block/Adminhtml/Template/Grid/Renderer/Image.php

```
 <?php
class My_Thumbnail_Block_Adminhtml_Template_Grid_Renderer_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $val = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($row, 'thumbnail')->resize(97);
    $out = "<img src=". $val ." width='97px'/>";
    return $out;
}
}
```

But No Columns have been added to the product grid and no images are shown.
Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you need to check each file residing in the folder app/etc/modules whether any file is replacing the category_product_tab and if there is some then merge that module with your one and you can enjoy both of your plugins.

Comment: Thanks @Vashikaran Samrat. This is a good advise. I will check through this for my new plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. This code is correct and has no problems. In my magento, I had previously installed a plugin for edit links in category products tab which I uninstalled and it worked.